# Reading Data from server and saving in txt file-iOS

Tags: ios, ios5, ios6

Is it good idea to save txt file in the application?

For example once user clicks on play button progress bar is activated, it gets data from server and data parsed and shown on the map and also at the same time each time stamp data is saved in txt file. Once progress bar is full and then resets itself and starts from 0 again.

Next cycle it wont read data from server but read data from saved txt file.

Do you think is it good idea? Please excuse my question, if it is

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think a good approach to that would be to store your data in a NSDictionary and save it to the app folder on the device as a *.plist file. Then you can load this data source and refresh it online whenever you choose.

Answer (score 0):

If the data you're saving is relatively simple, you should use `NSUserDefaults` instead of a text file. You won't have to worry about data parsing.

Comment: What if my saving is not simple, what would you recommend?

Comment: If you're not storing too many objects, but your objects are a bit complicated, you can have the object you want to save implement `NSCoding`, and save it to a plist.  If you're going to have many of these objects, then you will want to use Core Data.